# Ssh certificate authentication using certificate of type ssh-rsa-cert-v01

Tags: ssh, certificate, openssh, ssh-keygen

I have created a certificate using ssh-keygen and I couldn't find appropriate method in maverick latest package to establish a connection ..although maverick provides that feature. Where could I
load my private keys and certificates? As I couldn't use keystore, which is for maintaining certificates of type X.509.Kindly let me know of the method for authenticating ssh-rsa-cert-v01 type certificates..

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the certificate just as you would any public key. That means loading the certificate file that ends with "-cert.pub"

```
    SshPublicKey publicKey = SshKeyUtils.getPublicKey(
          new File("user_key-cert.pub"));
    SshPrivateKey privateKey = SshKeyUtils.getPrivateKey(
          new File("user_key"), "xxx"));

    SshKeyPair pair = new SshKeyPair();
    pair.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
    pair.setPublicKey(publicKey);
```

You can then present that for authentication as you would any normal SSH key.

```
    // Create SshClient
    SshClient ssh = SshConnector.createInstance()
           .connect(new SocketTransport("host", 22), "user"));
    ssh.authenticate(new PublicKeyAuthentication(pair));
```